# Nginx direct "fgrep" style redirects

Tags: nginx

I have a bunch of "redirect rules" that I'd like Nginx to do for me that look like this:

```
/news/?p=12312 ---> /news/some/new/url.html
/news/?p=12fsd312 ---> /news/some/new/url.html
```

How can I get Ngnix to redirect anyone who visits `/news/?p=12312` to `/news/some/new/url.html`?

I have tried

```
rewrite ^/news/?p=123$ /news/some/new/url.html last;
```

but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact is that `Nginx` considers everything after the `?` as a query string, not as part of the URI.

What i would do is compare the `query_string` value to trigger the Redirect. Something like this :

```
server {
   root /var/www;
   index  index.html;
   if ($arg_p = 12312) {
      rewrite ^ /news/some/new/url.html break;
   }
   if ($arg_p = 12fsd312) {
      rewrite ^ /news/some/new/url.html break;
   } 
}
```

Note that i've used `$arg_p` because your parameter is `p=123456`. For a parameter like `donaldDuck=123456` you would have to use `$arg_donaldDuck` (Hope i am clear).

To be more precise : `$arg_X` where `X` is the name of your parameter.